# Script adjustment : change to checkbox items on form instead of list items

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I found this script on YouTube by Jason Jurotich.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRlG58VKWNs.

Which allows update of numerous forms within a folder 
(question type = choose from list).

I wonder if this can be amended to also include checkbox questions as well.

I tried doubling the script and in the second part changing

```
var agentList = item.asListItem()     to    var agentList = item.asCheckboxItem()
```

This did not work. And I have searched for other scripts without success.

Script from Jason is as follows

```
function updateLists() {
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID HERE").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId())
   var items = form.getItems();
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
    var item = items[i]
    if (item.getTitle() === "QUESTION TITLE HERE"){
     var agentList = item.asListItem()
     }
    }
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SHEET NAME HERE");
  var agentValues = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var agentNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < agentValues.length; i++)   
    if(agentValues[i][0] != "")
    agentNames[i] = agentValues[i][0];
    agentList.setChoiceValues(agentNames);
 }
}
```

---

Mr Rebot - I try

```
function updateLists() {
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B8ZhY7dtctaMb0Vmb2RLdjhWM2M").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId())
   var items = form.getItems();
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
    var item = items[i]
    if (item.getTitle() === "EVENTS"){

     var agentList  = item.asCheckboxItem()//checkbox option
     var agentList = item.asListItem()//list option

     }
    }
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("EVENTS");
  var agentValues = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var agentNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < agentValues.length; i++)    
    if(agentValues[i][0] != "")
    agentNames[i] = agentValues[i][0];
    agentList.setChoiceValues(agentNames);
}}
```

And only the List Items update
Error : Invalid conversion for item type: LIST. (line 12, file "Code")

Perhaps its line one of the code ?

Comment: Looks that you are assigning the same name to two different functions.I think that when this occurs the first function will be ignored. By the other hand, if you didn't read yet https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting please to do it and if you still have problems with your code, include the error messages if any ocurrs, otherwise the result that you get.

Comment: Hi Ruben - I change the second function to : function updateLists2  and the onrun error is : Invalid conversion for item type : CHECKBOX (Line 11, file "Code")

Comment: The question was not edited after my today edit. Where do you made the change? Add those findings to your questions as part of your research progress (reference [ask]).

Comment: Instead of appending code revisions, replace the obsolete code with the new one. If you or other would like to see the details about how the question was evolving, you and others could see the revisions history by clicking on "edited nn ago" link (it's just blow the question tags)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are experiencing is that you are trying to make a multipleChoice type of question into a checkBox type (which will return an error like you experience). The tutorial you've watch shows how to dynamically change the options of the question in respect of the question type. I've tested your code and it is working if the question type of your form is checkBox.

code.gs

[image]

Sheet:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps clarify the issues you've encountered.

## EDIT

It would still would given that you have declared the correct type for each variable:

Code Sample:

```
var agentList = item.asListItem()//list option
var foodList  = item.asCheckboxItem()//checkbox option

//code for checkbox
if (item.getTitle() === "EVENTS"){

     var eventList  = item.asCheckboxItem()//checkbox option

     }

//code for list
if (item.getTitle() === "FOOD"){
     var foodList = item.asListItem()//list option

     }
```

## NOTE: Use different variable names to avoid conflict. As a suggestion create a function to keep your code clean and easy to follow. Add comment to help you track what you code does.

Comment: Hi Mr Rebot Thank you for your reply : your code works only if the folder contains Forms with checkbox questions - my folder contains both checkbox questions & list item questions - both of which I would like to update using the same spreadsheet column - if that is possible.

Comment: Hi - Here's the thing - I'm not a coder & have never used this kind of code - I find it overly complicated & extremely obtuse. It would be pointless to post all the things I have attempted in order to get Mr Rebot code to work without success. I get that you guys are trying to "point" me in the direction to steer me home ... but there are just too many "new" junctions & turns to fathom.

Comment: I understand your point, you might want to start with the basic steps e.g. one question type (checkbox) at a time. To be familiar with the do's and don't in coding. Also check the documents that can help, like [Apps Script Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Comment: Mr Rebot - your responses & those of Ruben ... simply ratify that this website is not a place to "ask questions" in the hope of getting answers ...  but a place to ask for guidance and "pointers" ... What I don't understand is  ... why is this not explained to posters in the first instance - to save everyone a whole heap of time ....